# Which branch(es) to keep pipeline YAMl files?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

To preface, my organization uses Github for its code base and Azure DevOps pipelines for its CI/CD.

I am building a DevOps CI/CD system for my organization and already have the tasks, jobs, and steps outlined to build and deploy. But I am unsure which branch to keep my YAML file(s) for best practice, and for developers to have to modify as little as possible after the pipeline is up.

My first instinct is to put the YAML file into our `develop` branch, as that is where most of the stable changes will be during research. The trigger will be triggered on any PR or commit to `develop`.

My issue with this approach is that if a developer branches a feature or bugfix from the `develop` branch, then the trigger will still be from `develop` in that feature or bugfix branch, which would cause multiple pipeline runs to be triggered, once for each active feature or bugfix branch that is still up when `develop` is modified.
We could ask the developers to manually change the trigger in the YAML file from `develop` to something else after a branch is created , but ideally the process is as hands off as possible.

My next idea was to have a dedicated branch, named `DevOps` in the repository that contains only a YAML file. This would trigger on `develop`.

However, this would cause any PR on `develop` to not have the 'pre-check' that would be automatically displayed if the YAML file was in `develop`.

So I ask, what is standard or best practice for keeping YML files and setting triggers? And how do you structure it in your project?

Comment: You don't keep a pipeline in any particular branch. The pipeline goes into the repository, and then you configure the circumstances under which it runs via triggers. I don't understand what issue you're having.

Comment: In Azure at least, the YAML file needs to be in the repository I thought. Is there a different way to store it if not in one or more of the repository branches?

Comment: You're looking at it wrong. The pipeline YAML doesn't go into a *single* branch, it goes into *every* branch. Your YAML should be treated **exactly the same** as application code.

Comment: I see, but if multiple branches are all configured to triggered from develop, won't they all go off when any change to develop is made?

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about *something*, but I can't tell what. **Every branch** should have a copy of the **exact same YAML** (unless, of course, you're making changes to it). Within the YAML, there should be triggers defined. If you only want it to trigger when a change is made to `develop`, then you *only include a trigger for `develop`*. If you want it to trigger on multiple branches, you can specify multiple branches, including wildcards like `feature/*`. It will queue *one* pipeline run any time a change is made on the branches with triggers defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### CI Triggers in YAML pipeline:

If you want the pipeline can be triggered for a branch, the YAML file must be existing in that branch, and the [branches filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) set on the CI triggers should include current branch at least.

1. The YAML pipelines can be triggered for **`bugfix`** branch in the following scenarios:

   - The YAML file is in the **`bugfix`** branch and has the branches filter like as below.

     ```yaml
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
         - bugfix  # Include bugfix branch.
         . . .
     ```

     OR

     ```yaml
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
         - '*'  # Include any branch.
         . . .
     ```
2. The YAML pipelines cannot be triggered for **`bugfix`** branch in the following scenarios:

   - The YAML file is in the **`bugfix`** branch and has the branches filter like as below.

     ```yaml
     trigger:
       branches:
         exclude:
         - bugfix  # Exclude bugfix branch.
         . . .
     ```
   - The YAML file is not in the **`bugfix`** branch, even if has the branches filter like as below.

     ```yaml
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
         - bugfix  # Include bugfix branch.
         . . .
     ```

     OR

     ```yaml
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
         - '*'  # Include any branch.
         . . .
     ```

---

##### PR Triggers in YAML pipeline for GitHub:

It is recommended to ensure the YAML file is existing in both source branch and target branch of the PR. And ensure the [branches filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) set on the PR triggers should include the target branch at least.

---

Comment: Thank you, the clarification on triggers is just what I needed! So essentially, for a trigger to work, the YAML file must both include a branch name and must be in that branch?